# SpeechRecognition is installed but not importing in PyCharm CE

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, speech-recognition

I have installed SpeechRecognition by using `pip install SpeechRecognition` but whenever I'm trying to import that in the IDE (PyCharm CE) it's not working and marking as an error.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

I'm using macOS and in the `'/Users/benzir/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages'` directory I have found a folder named `'speech_recognition'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution to this problem.

I have simply changed the environment to `Conda Environment` from default in the Python Interpreter. Now It's working fine. :)